# When using factory_bot (formerly factory_girl) with RSpec to test in Rails, undefined method "first"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have an RSpec test that uses factory_bot to create instances. The test passes except when the *first* method is used in a view.

This is the code being tested:

```
def order_confirm_email(id, items, order, address, coupon)
    @user = User.find(id)
    @items = items
    @order = order
    @address = address
    if coupon == nil
      @coupon = ''
    else
      @coupon = coupon.discount
    end

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Order completed')
  end
```

This is the test:

```
it 'sends an email upon checkout process completion' do
      user    = create(:user)
      items   = create(:base_item)
      order   = create(:base_item)
      address = create(:address)
      coupon  = create(:coupon)

      expect(orderConfirmationMail.subject).to eq('Order completed')
    end
```

So far so good. But when one of the views attempts to access the first instance, as below:

```
<h1>Order id - <%= @order.first.id %></h1>
```

Then I receive the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) UserMailer user_emails sends an email upon checkout process completion
     Failure/Error: <!-- <h1>Order id - <%= @order.first.id %></h1> -->

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `first' for 3:Fixnum
```

According to my understanding, the instances should be persisting since I use *create* instead of *build*. But apparently that is not happening. Changing the view is not an option except as a last resort. How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the **order_items.rb** Factory file:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :base_item, class: OrderItem do
    item_name_en "Sample Item"
    item_link "http://www.foo.com"
    qty 5
    available_qty 100
    item_price 10
    seller_name "foo"
    status "foo"

    foo_item_id "123456"
    foo_id "654321"
  end

  factory :order_item1, parent: :base_item do
    foo_item_id "123456"
    foo_seller_id "654321"
    association :order
  end

  factory :order_item2, parent: :base_item do
    foo_item_id "123457"
    foo_seller_id "654321"
  end

  factory :order_item3, parent: :base_item do
    foo_item_id "123458"
    foo_seller_id "654322"
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I am encountering a similar issue when writing another test. I receive the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) UserMailer user_emails sends an email upon abandoned cart
     Failure/Error: <% @items.each do |item| %>

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum
```

This seems to indicate that it is not an issue with the *first* method per se, but rather with the interpolated Ruby in the views throwing an error when I run RSpec. This generalizes the problem and hopefully makes it more easily solvable.

Comment: your order is type `integer` so I believe there is something wrong with your factory. you did not include the `base_item` factory. when you do `order = create(:base_item)` you must have a factory where you define that `base_item` and I would need to see it.

Comment: I have added the relevant factory file above.

Comment: `orderConfirmationMail` vs `order_confirm_email`, which is it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that is not an issue, as earlier in the spec I include this line that I know is working correctly because I use the same format in another test successfully: `let(:orderConfirmationMail) { UserMailer.order_confirm_email(1,2,3,4,nil) }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that is not an issue, as earlier in the spec I include this line that I know is working correctly because I use the same format in another test successfully
>
> `let(:orderConfirmationMail) { UserMailer.order_confirm_email(1,2,3,4,nil) }`

There it is. If you included this line from the start, your question would've been answered in two seconds.

Considering the signature of `order_confirm_email`

```
def order_confirm_email(id, items, order, address, coupon)
```

Why do you think `order` is set to 3? **Because you pass it this way!**

Mystery solved.

Comment: @223seneca Nice. Now I also get it. He was not using the factory, but setting the instance variable `@order` by calling the method `UserMailer.order_confirm_email(1,2,3,4,nil)` and consequently setting `@order = 3`. You solved the problem Sergio. I believe @223seneca should accept your answer as the correct solution.

Comment: This does in fact answer the question as I stated it, so I will accept as the solution. It seems there is a deeper issue with my factories not working somehow that I will need to solve now. Any problems from that will be posted as a separate question.

Comment: @223seneca: your factories are working just fine, I'm willing to bet. You just don't use the built objects.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I certainly hope that is the case. If you don't mind helping me a bit further, how do I properly access those built objects? This is my first time using both RSpec and factory_bot, and I'm working with some inherited code from a developer no longer at our company, so I'm sort of learning as I go.

Comment: @223seneca: extract them in `let` blocks. Check out the first green examples here: http://www.betterspecs.org/#let

And read through the whole thing, it's incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I don't have any idea. I would give a look to your `OrderItem` model, also I don't get why you do `@order.first` because that is just 1 object. Could make sense to me `@orders.first`  but not `@order.first`. When things don't make sense in `rails` it is hard to build applications. also `order` and `item` should be two different models, we use `order_items` for building joins between two different models

An order can have many or just one item, you decide the relationship.

with `rspec` you can debug and also you can test your factories in the `rails c test` environment. There you can check what is the result of `create(:base_item)` or of `FactoryGirl.create(:base_item)`

I believe that should be an object, so I don't understand why it is saying `undefined method 'first' for 3:Fixnum`

Maybe the you `factory` is not what we expect

but you can understand this by debugging and testing in the console your factory

Comment: I tried debugging in the console but could not identify the source of my troubles.

Does Update 2 provide additional useful context for you?

Comment: @223seneca you problem is solved. Sergio Tulentsev solved this issue. You can open a new issue if you have other problem. Also you need to accept the answer from Sergio because I read it and it is the solution to your problem

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio: it's not so much a "solution", it just points out the source of the problem :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev his problem defined from the title `When using factory_bot (formerly factory_girl) with RSpec to test in Rails, undefined method “first”` was solved. Now another error message is showing, but he should write a new question in my opinion and include all the relevant information for that issue.